# Please explain Paralle and Grouping execution using TestNG and explain the code in testng.xml file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Please explain the testng.xml to run the test scripts in parallel and grouping using TestNG in Selenium webdriver.Explain what and parameters should be given in testNG.xml for parallel and grouping execution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to manipulate with Paralle and Grouping execution using TestNG:

- in pom.xml
- in testng.xml

**POM.xml**

***1. Using Groups***

TestNG allows you to group your tests. You can then execute one or more specific groups. To do this with Surefire, use the groups parameter, for example:

```
<plugins>
[...]
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.17</version>
<configuration>
<groups>functest,perftest</groups>
</configuration>
</plugin>
[...]
</plugins>
```

Likewise, the excludedGroups parameter can be used to run all but a certain set of groups.

***2. Running tests in parallel***

TestNG allows you to run your tests in parallel, including JUnit tests. To do this, you must set the parallel parameter, and may change the threadCount parameter if the default of 5 is not sufficient. For example:

```
</plugins>
[...]
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.17</version>
<configuration>
<parallel>methods</parallel>
<threadCount>10</threadCount>
</configuration>
</plugin>
[...]
</plugins>
```

More details here- http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

**TESTNG.XML**

1. There are a lot of details and examples about ***group execution*** here - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_group_test.htm
2. Here are some examples about ***parallelism*** - http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running